# what will be the code in python if I have to add a series taking the values on a gap of 3

Tags: python, math

I know the code for calculating the sum of an infinite series in python.
But I always get stuck when I have to make a jump of a specific integer.
For example- to calculate the sum of this series-

```
expectation = nsum(lambda x: x*(1/2**(x+1)),[0,inf])
```

But if I want that x should take values 4,7,10,13..., i.e. on a gap of three, then what should be the code?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason why you would use a lambda function? It makes your code alot less readable. The % operator is one of the ways to be able to take gaps in lists.

```
sum = 0
for x in range(4,100000,3):
    x *= 1/2**(x+1)
    sum += x
```

an alternative is to make a list of the numbers and use list position to get every third item in the list. For example:

```
l = list(range(10000))
l = l[::3]
```

If you really need to try it with a lambda function you could try it like this:

```
expectation = sum(map(lambda x: x*(1/2**(x+1)) if x%3==0 else 0,range(1000)))
```

The map function passes the range 1000 numbers one by one to the lambda. The lambda function only executes if the number passed can be devided by 3 (so steps of 3).

Comment: you could have used `for x in range(4,100000,3):`

Comment: You are right, that is alot more elegant. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: `expectation = sum(map(lambda x: x*(1/2**(x+1)) if x%3==0 else 0,range(1000))) ` this can also be changed to `expectation = sum(map(lambda x: x*(1/2**(x+1)) ,range(4,1000,3)))`